# Is there any change in temperature due to special relativity?

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, temperature, observers

Say I am travelling in a spaceship very close to the speed of light. Would there be any change in temperature in the spaceship relative to outside the spaceship? Please explain in detail.

Comment: @BenCrowell Just edited the question

Comment: You **are** traveling very close to the speed of light.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect

Comment: Not due to the relative velocity. Only if you are accelerating. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect (this is just a prediction at the time of writing)